# Excess Mortality versus Relative Mortality

Tags: survival, hazard, relative-risk, mortality

I have modeled the relative mortality of a US cancer cohort, but I want to apply the results to a cohort from the UK (this is the best option as there was no available UK data).

Initially I thought the relative mortality would be a good option, but have lately been thinking I should use the excess mortality instead, because given a similar distribution of cause of the death, the absolute impact of cancer is likely the same in the UK as in the US regardless of the base mortality risk.

Does anyone have any thoughts on which measure is the better for conversion to a different population than the one under study?

Answer (score 2):

They are completely different measures. I recommend reading the paper:

> Perme, Maja Pohar, Janez Stare, and Jacques Estève. "[On estimation in relative survival](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2011.01640.x/full)." Biometrics 68.1 (2012): 113-120.

The basic idea is that relative survival is the ratio of the means of the survival of the individuals and the population survival, while the net/excess survival is the mean of the ratios of the survivals (the denominator is always the population survival of the group of interest). So, their interpretation is different.